# Equivalence of probability density (mass) functions

Tags: probability-theory

Say that we have two probability density (or mass) functions $f,g$ for a random variable $X$, and that in general $f\neq g$ as functions. Is there a definition or something that allow us to say that $f$ and $g$ are equivalent probability density (mass) functions for $X$? Of course equivalent in everything that matters for probability and statistics.

Thanks

Comment: $f=g$ almost everywhere / almost surely?

Comment: I had thought on equality as functions, but I see that almost everywhere is a good choice. What is almost surely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two PMFs describe the same distribution if and only if they are equal as functions (i.e. at each point). Two PDFs describe the same distribution if and only if they are equal Lebesgue-almost everywhere.